# How do i verify total token mint and total token reserved are the same after a transfer between kusama parachains?

Tags: parachain, kusama, xcm, transfer

Scenario:
Transfer token A from parachain_1 to parachain_2

I can verify the amount of token A issued on parachain_2 by looking at token A's total issuance on parachain_2 but how can i find the total token A reserved?

I believe this diagram describes the details of this transfer:
https://www.figma.com/file/9WoqPIRBv2zh23yt8LGU0c/XCM-Transfer-Reserve-Asset?node-id=0%3A1

In this case do i need to query the holding register of token A on kusama? If so, how do i query that? Or can this value be derived another way?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the configuration/logic you are using for your chain.

For the most common XCM configuration, the reserved balance goes to the parachain_2's sovereign account on parachain_1.

---

For example, our parachain is Crab Parachain. We reserve transfer some Crab to Karura(paraid 2000).

Let's calculate the Karura's sovereign address first.

```
subalfred key --type sibling 2000
public-key 0x7369626cd0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SiblId(2000)
Substrate 5Eg2fntJ27qsari4FGrGhrMqKFDRnkNSR6UshkZYBGXmSuC8
```

Then check at the [`5Eg2fntJ27qsari4FGrGhrMqKFDRnkNSR6UshkZYBGXmSuC8` on Crab Parachain](https://crab-parachain.subscan.io/account/5Eg2fntJ27qsari4FGrGhrMqKFDRnkNSR6UshkZYBGXmSuC8).